# If I have a two-state Markov Chain, and I start a chain at state 1, and another at state 2, what is the expected time before they hit?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

I have a two-state Markov Chain that looks like:

$$
 P= \left(\begin{matrix} 0.4 &0.6 \\
 0.7 & 0.3 \end{matrix} \right).
$$

From this, suppose I define $X_t$ and $Y_t$, where $X_t$ starts at state 1 above (corresponding to $0.4,0.6$), and $Y_t$ starts at state 2. I would like to find the expected time before they coincide for the first time. I have identified that my problem will be first defining $\tau = min\{n\geq 1:X_n \neq Y_n\}$. Then, I'd like to find $E[\tau] = E[min\{n\geq 1:X_n \neq Y_n\}]$. However, I am not sure even where to begin. I think that perhaps I am failing to see a trick. Does anyone know of any tricks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They will coincide(for the first time) on the step where one changes state and the other does not.    They will not do so on any step where both either do or donut change.   The probability measure of these events (at any step) does not care which entity is in which state, by symmetry, only that they are in different states.   Thus the count of steps until coincidence has a geometric$_1$ distribution.

$$N\sim\mathcal{Geo}_1(p) ~\iff~ \mathsf E(N) = \dfrac{1}{p}$$

Can you evaluate $p$ using your matrix?

Comment: I think I do, so basically due to the Markov property we only have to evaluate what happens at a specific time with disregard to the past. In this case, there are two ways in which the first and the second chain can meet. The 1st is when the first chain in at 0, and the 2nd chain is at 1, and the 1st moves from 0 to 1 and the 2nd moves from 1 to 1. The 2nd is when the 1st chain in at 1, and the 2nd chain is at 0, and the 1st moves from 1 to 0 and the 2nd moves from 0 to 0. By symmetry, we can multiply by 2 (switch chains' labels) to get: $p = 2(0.6 \cdot 0.3 + 0.7 \cdot 0.4) = 0.92$.

Comment: @user136503 Close. You don't need to multiply by two. The symmetry is that we don't care *which* state the entities are both in, only that they aren't in the same state.   $p=(0.6\cdot 0.3+0.4\cdot 0.7)=0.46$ . As a reality check: the probability that they either both do switch or both do not is:  $(0.6\cdot 0.7 +0.4\cdot 0.3) = 0.54 = 1-p$